# Auto-Run celdas pandas/python

Tags: python, pandas

tengo este codigo..
#https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aVIuNgWKLOzIjDeD2SPp13G9xDsHEhgtpNELa0BLplE/edit#gid=2143913497
import pandas as pd
sheet_id='1aVIuNgWKLOzIjDeD2SPp13G9xDsHEhgtpNELa0BLplE'
cols5='B:I'
xls=pd.ExcelFile(f'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{sheet_id}/export?format=xlsx')
Rtas=pd.read_excel(xls,'Rtas',usecols=cols5)
Rtas

Es un google sheet que son respuestas a distintas preguntas de una encuesta.

necesito que se vaya actualizando constantemente (en mi python) ya que es una base de datos de una encuesta.... pero como hago? Con un while? Alguien me podria ayudar? Gracias a todos!!

Comment: Supongo que podrias usar el programador de tareas del servidor en el que vayas a correr tu programa (si es que tiene uno) para que ejecute el script cada x tiempo. Otra alternativa es un while junto a un time.sleep, ya que si haces muchos requests en poco tiempo te podrian bloquear.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.